# Roslyn Analyzer Select Document Changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, code-analysis, codefixprovider

I'm trying to figure out how I can select Individual changes for updating issues in a document.  When you select a code action to fix an issue.  There are 3 additional options fix for document/project/solution:

[image]

The window reflect the full change set that would be updated for a document.  As you can see in the Example which uses the default analyzer.  We are only given the option to either update all classes in the document to be upper case or none of them.

How can I register a change so that it creates an indiviual check box for each change that would be made to the document and not the full change set?

Comment: There is probably no way to do that.

Comment: @SLaks I though so too, but one of my extensions is actually seperating them in some instances but I'm not too sure why